# Ansible paybook to disable different user in different servers

Tags: ansible

I have a list of users in multiple servers like

```
- Server1
  - User1
  - User2

- Server2
  - User7
  - User10

- Server5
  - User4
  - User9
```

How can I disable those users using ansible in this case?

Comment: What have you tried that failed? Can you provide a playbook that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

There are more options. The code depends on where the data comes from. For example, if the data is a dictionary, the playbook below does the job

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    users_rm:
      Server1:
        - User1
        - User2
      Server2:
        - User7
        - User10
      Server5:
        - User4
        - User9
  tasks:
    - name: Remove users
      users:
        state: absent
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users_rm[inventory_hostname]|default([]) }}"
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

See module [users](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#user-manage-user-accounts).